# The moderation philosophy regarding editing

Tags: discussion, editing

If different SE sites can have their own policies to a degree, my question is about Linguistics.SE’s moderation principles / philosophy (if they were decided at some point) regarding *editing*.

I recognize Stack Exchange is the culmination of years of collaborative efforts and share trial and errors so I am curious to know more about if it is considered general site practice to be sparing in the degree to which you edit.

I can see that making sense, but my initial impulse was to edit more freely to make content better in the long run - reformulating a question in a much purer form, to me, helps everybody (especially the person asking it).

Is there a rule of thumb about how much to edit or not edit, beyond, “I made it better”?

1. Are there rules of thumb regarding respecting posts as someone else’s property, and not changing their preferred manner of expression or subdetails added in? (I assume yes, just haven’t seen it written explicitly, so far.)
2. Is editing meant to be restrained in order to train participants to make better content themselves? (Also assumed to be yes, like above.)

Is there a site-specific discussion about this or is this a Stack Exchange Meta, site-wide general topic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tension to editing, because there's a sense in which all posts belong to the community rather than the original author (so edits can't be refused by the author), but posts are still by their original authors, and so shouldn't be edited in ways that change the author's purpose for the post.

There are lots of posts on MSE that explain the general philosophy, I found this one helpful: [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/256282)

I'd agree with the second-top answer that edits should generally be **copy edits**. So these things are encouraged:

- fixing typos or formatting
- improving grammar
- adding links for uncommon topics to resources like Wikipedia
- making small changes to improve the clarity of a post
- adding details that an author has written in a comment but not edited into the post themselves

But on the other side, edits shouldn't:

- change what a question is asking or what an answer is primarily saying
- turn an unclear question into a clear one when that can only be done by guessing the intention of the asker - we have to be careful here because we may think that the meaning of a question is obvious and we may miss ambiguities that others are seeing
- bolster an answer by adding new arguments
- adding references or citations that the original author may not have read themselves

If your edit would be adding new intellectual insights then it's almost always better to just post a new answer or even a new question yourself.

Comment: Gotcha. Will try to abide by that then. It could be interesting to try to assemble all this stuff in one place, like a community moderation guide that tries to get pretty precise ?

Comment: Curious about commenting as well, if anyone has developed a clean rule of thumb analogous to “copy-editing”, like, how conversational can it be; is the longterm goal to clean up back and forth if it could create a cleaner overall page, as a reference material. ? “Comments are for asking clarifying information or adding more information”. Are comments deleted that don’t ultimately do either, or how conversational can they be and be allowed to remain? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387864/what-is-best-practice-for-the-use-of-comments-vs-answers

Comment: @hmltn Comments should not be conversational at all. That's what chat is for.

Comment: Officially, at least. In fact that policy doesn't work on ELU or this SE. There's no right answers for most of them, and they're frequently based on nonsense or factlessness. As for these rules, what's wrong with adding sources? Some of them are hard to find. And new arguments are useful if there's a useful theory (though that's not the norm).

Comment: @jlawler If you want to add new theories or sources please just write your own answer. There's no problem having more answers with new information.

Comment: Most of the information in linguistic theories is [invented by the theoretician](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler//theory.how.html) (and of course, since they invented them, they get to name them, using their own terms for the definition). This is not the same as "more answers with new information".

Comment: @jlawler I'd say that is just applying a **grid** to whatever the samples are.